# Compare 2 users lists python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to compare 2 lists [new_user] and [current_user] and verify if new user is already in current user (no case sensitive)

```
current_users = ['john', 'anne', 'matthew', 'yennefer', 'tony']
new_users = ['paul', 'frank', 'carl', 'nana', 'JOHN']
current_users.extend(new_users[0:2])
lower_user = []

for new_user in new_users:
    lower_user.append(new_user.lower())
    if lower_user in current_users:
        print("Name unavaible, " + str(new_user))
    else:
        print("Name available, " + str(new_user))

Actually, that's the output:
Name available, paul
Name available, frank
Name available, carl
Name available, nana
Name available, JOHN
```

JOHN is available, so isn't working.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, your if statement is basically saying if the **list** `lower_user` is in the list `current_users`, then do something. Instead, you want to see if the previously appended result in `lower_user` is in `current_users`. Do this by adding the index `[-1]` to the `lower_user` list.

```
current_users = ['john', 'anne', 'matthew', 'yennefer', 'tony']
new_users = ['paul', 'frank', 'carl', 'nana', 'JOHN']
current_users.extend(new_users[0:2])
lower_user = []

for new_user in new_users:
    lower_user.append(new_user.lower())
    if lower_user[-1] in current_users:
        print("Name unavailable, " + str(new_user))
    else:
        print("Name available, " + str(new_user))
```

This provides the output:

```
Name unavailable, paul
Name unavailable, frank
Name available, carl
Name available, nana
Name unavailable, JOHN
```

If this is the intended output, great. If not, please provide what the expected output is.

You could also simplify this a lot and eliminate appending to the `lower_user` list by just comparing it directly.

```
current_users = ['john', 'anne', 'matthew', 'yennefer', 'tony']
new_users = ['paul', 'frank', 'carl', 'nana', 'JOHN']
current_users.extend(new_users[0:2])

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.lower() in current_users:
        print("Name unavailable, " + str(new_user))
    else:
        print("Name available, " + str(new_user))
```

I do find it interesting that you extend the `current_users` list to include the first two values in `new_users` with the line `current_users.extend(new_users[0:2])`, but I digress.

Comment: MY BAD BOY, YEAH, IT IS IT. THANKS FOR THE HELP.

Comment: Totally forgotted that i added 2 other uses besides John to current_users. But why exactly adding [-1] provided this output?

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html list.append(x) adds a value to the end of a list.The [-1] is the index of the last item in the list (the most recently appended value).